# JPA@Google App Engine: JPQL SELECT queries always return empty results

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

I'm currently migrating a JPA-2.0-based application from Hibernate to Google App Engine since I just want to run it there.

I'm stucked, because I cannot get any results from SELECT queries. I can persist entities and find them by there id, but if I want to retrieve all existing entities with a SELECT query, the result is empty.

I isolated this issue in one simple test case:

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="google.transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.singletonEMFForName" value="true"/>^
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**JPA entity class**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
class TestEntity
{
    @Id
    String id;
    String name;

    TestEntity(String id, String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // For deseralization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private TestEntity()
    {
    }
}
```

**Failing JUnit-Test**

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

public class SimpleJpaTest
{
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "google.transactions-optional";
    private static final EntityManagerFactory EMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);

    private final LocalServiceTestHelper _helper;

    public SimpleJpaTest()
    {
        _helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100));
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        _helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown()
    {
        _helper.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPersistAndGet()
    {
        String id = "test";
        String name = "Test";

        // Persist entity
        EntityManager entityManager1 = EMF.createEntityManager();
        entityManager1.getTransaction().begin();
        TestEntity entity1 = new TestEntity(id, name);
        entityManager1.persist(entity1);
        entityManager1.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager1.close();

        // Find specific entity
        EntityManager entityManager2 = EMF.createEntityManager();
        entityManager2.getTransaction().begin();
        TestEntity result2 = entityManager2.find(TestEntity.class, id);
        entityManager2.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager2.close();

        assertNotNull(result2); // succeeds
        assertEquals(id, result2.id); // succeeds
        assertEquals(name, result2.name); // succeeds

        // Get all entities
        EntityManager entityManager3 = EMF.createEntityManager();
        entityManager3.getTransaction().begin();
        String queryString3 = "SELECT e from TestEntity e";
        TypedQuery<TestEntity> query3 = entityManager3.createQuery(queryString3, TestEntity.class);
        List<TestEntity> result3 = query3.getResultList();
        entityManager3.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager3.close();

        assertNotNull(result3); // succeeds
        assertFalse(result3.isEmpty()); // fails
        assertEquals(1, result3.size());
        assertNotNull(result3.get(0));
        assertEquals(id, result3.get(0).id);
        assertEquals(name, result3.get(0).name);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the retrieval of a single entity via find() works well, but not the SELECT query. The same code works fine with Hibernate.

---

Edit due to DataNucleus' comment:

**Console output**

```
Jan 30, 2013 2:41:10 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class SimpleJpaTest was specified in persistence-unit google.transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: High Replication
    Storage: In-memory
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit
INFO: >> calling preCommit on org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2@15b573da
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit
INFO: >> calling preCommit on org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@5ede1ffa
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl preFlush
INFO: >> calling preFlush on org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2@15b573da
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl preFlush
INFO: >> calling preFlush on org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@5ede1ffa
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM com.google.appengine.datanucleus.MetaDataValidator validate
INFO: Performing appengine-specific metadata validation for TestEntity
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM com.google.appengine.datanucleus.MetaDataValidator validate
INFO: Finished performing appengine-specific metadata validation for TestEntity
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit
INFO: >> calling preCommit on org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2@49c54f01
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit
INFO: >> calling preCommit on org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@69eeff74
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl preFlush
INFO: >> calling preFlush on org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2@49c54f01
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl preFlush
INFO: >> calling preFlush on org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@69eeff74
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl preFlush
INFO: >> calling preFlush on org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2@16f650e5
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl preFlush
INFO: >> calling preFlush on org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@71fcf7e2
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit
INFO: >> calling preCommit on org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2@16f650e5
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit
INFO: >> calling preCommit on org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@71fcf7e2
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl preFlush
INFO: >> calling preFlush on org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2@16f650e5
Jan 30, 2013 1:41:11 PM org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl preFlush
INFO: >> calling preFlush on org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@71fcf7e2
```

---

btw: This issue seems to be similar to [Google App Engine + google cloud sql jpa query does not retrieve data from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593464/google-app-engine-google-cloud-sql-jpa-query-does-not-retrieve-data-from-datab), but there is no answer yet.

Comment: I'd have though the first point of call would have been the log, since that's why those things exist. Post what appears in the log for the query. It will tell you what is executed in the GAE datastore

Comment: Added console output. Doesn't really help me. Are there some other logs?

Comment: the log would help you if you had it turned on at DEBUG level

Comment: How can I do that? My logging.properties file seems to be ignored.

Comment: that is standard java.util.logging, so suggest a search for it. GAE JPA plugin simply uses the logging provided by the platform

Comment: I just found the VM option -Djava.util.logging.config.file for my JUnit run configuration, but in "standard java.util.logging" there is no "DEBUG level" and turning it to ALL gives the same output as shown above.

Comment: "DEBUG" (Log4j parlance) is "FINE"(or below) in java.util.logging

Comment: Since FINE or anything else prints not more than ALL, there are no other logs than those I have already posted.

Comment: There are other log messages output, since DataNucleus would print a pile of information at FINE, its just configuring the log to show them

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will be much easier for me to stay with Hibernate and use [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) than migrating to [App Engine Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/)...